# How to add a background to listview? -Android

Tags: android, image, list, view, colors

I have a listview activity with a bunch of single textview items. Here's my item:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >    
</TextView>
```

As you can see, the text color is white, and the background is transparent. (I tried putting alpha from 0 to 100, it either shows white background or black)

Now in the listview, I have put in an image in the background called "s4":

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/s4">
</ListView>
```

I want to make the listview items sort of translucent such that the background image can be viewed.

Each item should be translucent, the text should be white and visible, and the listview's background should be visible.

I can't seem to get it right, I can put in a solid color, but I want the items to scroll over a fixed background image.

What am I doing wrong?
(there are several questions like this, but all are unsolved.)

EDIT:

http://postimg.org/image/4yjh7fiwp/

Here's the screenie, Look VERY closely you can see the text, (try pressing CTRL+A)
But color of the text is not a problem, white text is fine since my background image is blackish ...I just want the listview and it's items to be translucent.

The screenie is pretty much the same with what I did, and with suggestion given by swapnil...No change at all.

Comment: can u post the screen shot of the listvie ?

Comment: Done, it's in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that list backdrnd will not white other wise text will not visible.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSongs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/s4"
/>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@android:color/transpernt"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >    
</TextView>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that gave no change at all... whatsoever , I have included the screenie as to how it looks after I type in these edits...